# using sed to replace a newline that starts with any digit

Tags: sed

I've been googling this and can't find an answer that works. I have a file where most lines start with a character string. However, there are several lines that start with a number (of varying lengths). I want to use sed to remove the newline characters from these lines so that the numbers and stuff that follows end up on the preceding lines.

I am working on a mac so am in a bash shell.

Example:

```
Test 1,2,3,
41
Test 5,6,7,
8800
Test 9, 10
Test 11, 12
```

Should end up:

```
Test 1,2,3,41
Test 5,6,7,8800
Test 9, 10
Test 11, 12
```

Answer (score 3):

a short `sed` will do:

```sh
sed -zE 's/(,)[[:space:]]*[\n\r]+/\1/g'
```

`sed` parameters breakdown:

- `-z`: use null terminated lines to allow sed search replace newline characters.
- `-E`: use extended RegEx syntax
- `'s/(,)[[:space:]]*[\n\r]+/\1/g'`: search `,` followed by maybe some spaces and any number of newlines or linefeeds and replace by the captured `,`. Result is it will remove the newline and trailing spaces when there is nothing after the last `,`

output produced:

```
Test 1,2,3,41
Test 5,6,7,8800
Test 9, 10
Test 11, 12
```

Comment: Nice one for a `sed` that supports the `z` and `E` options.  I'm not sure Mac `sed` does, as I expect it to follow BSD, whose `sed` knows `-E` but not `-z`.  If the OP has or can install GNU `sed`, though, then this is short and sweet.

Comment: Great. Thanks, `@Léa Gris`. How to delete them instead of replacing?

Answer (score 2):

`sed` processes one line at a time.  It is possible to use it to join lines, but once you output a line *without* joining the following line to it, it's too late.

You'll probably get an answer suggesting that you do this with `awk`, and that might indeed be better, but since you asked specifically about `sed`, it *is* possible to use it for the purpose.  There are several ways to do it. This one should work with any POSIX-conforming `sed`:

```
 sed ':1; $ { s/\n\([0-9]\)/\1/g; n }; N; b1'
```

Explanation: the `sed` expression is a series of semicolon-delimited commands that could be expressed more verbosely (and with explanatory comments) as

```
# Label for looping back to the start of this script
  :1

# If we're on the last line
$ {
    # Remove all newlines that are immediately followed by a digit
    s/\n\([0-9]\)/\1/g

    # Finish this sed cycle, printing the result (will terminate because no more lines)
    n
  }

# Append a newline to the pattern space, followed by the next line of input
  N

# jump to label 1
  b1
```

In other words, it will slurp up all the input, then perform all the substitutions in one go.  Although quite different from theirs, this was inspired by @LéaGris's version.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/\n[0-9]/s/\n//;P;D' file
```

Append the next line and if that line begins with a number, remove the newline. Print and then delete the first line in the pattern space and repeat.

N.B. This does not slurp the entire file into memory, but keeps at most two lines only in the pattern space.

Comment: Nice.  I was looking for something along these lines, but didn't recognize how the `D` command would facilitate it.

Answer (score 1):

If line that missing numbers ends with a comma `,`, you can do:

```
awk '{printf /,$/?"%s":"%s\n",$0}' file
Test 1,2,3,41
Test 5,6,7,8800
Test 9, 10
Test 11, 12
```

It prints newline depending of comma or not a comma at end of line.